# Moving from one place to another over time (or rotating) in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with moving from one place to another in Unity over time. I would like my character to move from current position to current + 1 on Y. Unfortunately, looks like it does not get the current position properly or something, since if I debug what I wrote, it says that the magnitude is always 1, so the point is moving with me. Shouldn't it just check the current position and add 1 to Y, move to that position and then check again? I have no idea what's wrong with this code, or if it's strictly connected with how Unity checks positions and things in real time?

```
 public bool moving = false;
 private Vector3 dir;
 void FrontMovement()
 {
     Vector3 movement = new Vector3(-Mathf.Sin(transform.eulerAngles.z * Mathf.PI / 180), Mathf.Cos(transform.eulerAngles.z * Mathf.PI / 180), 0f); // always moving front, even after rotation

     if (moving == false)
     {
         dir = movement - transform.position;
         moving = true;
         return;
     }
     transform.Translate(dir.normalized * Time.deltaTime);
     if(dir.magnitude <= Time.deltaTime)
     {
         Debug.Log("Finished movement");
         moving = false;
     }
 }
 void FixedUpdate()
 {
     Debug.Log(dir.magnitude);
     FrontMovement();
 }
```

I would also like to know how to do rotations over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html

lerp also works for rotations

```
// Movement speed in units per second.
public float speed = 1.0F;

// Time when the movement started.
private float startTime;

// Total distance between the markers.
private float journeyLength;

void StartMoving() {
    // Keep a note of the time the movement started.
    startTime = Time.time;

    Vector3 modifiedPosition = transform.position;
    transform.position.y += 1.0f;

    // Calculate the journey length.
    journeyLength = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, modifiedPosition.position);

    moving = true;
}

// Move to the target end position.
void Update()
{
    if (moving) {
    // Distance moved equals elapsed time times speed..
    float distCovered = (Time.time - startTime) * speed;

    // Fraction of journey completed equals current distance divided by total distance.
    float fractionOfJourney = distCovered / journeyLength;

    // Set our position as a fraction of the distance between the markers.
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startMarker.position, endMarker.position, fractionOfJourney);

        if (fractionOfJourney >= 1.0f) {
        moving = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) + [Vector3.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) to move with a specified amount of time:

```
public IEnumerator MoveToPosition(Transform transform, Vector3 position, float timeToMove)
{
      var currentPos = transform.position;
      var t = 0f;
      while(t <= 1f)
      {
             t += Time.deltaTime / timeToMove;
             transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(currentPos, position, t);
             yield return null;
      }
      transform.position = position;
}
```

you call the coroutine in Start Method

```
StartCoroutine(MoveToPosition(transform, newposition, timeToMove))
```

You could use the same logic for Rotating, with [Quaternion.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Lerp.html) or [Slerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html) and [Quaternion.LookRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html), of course you have lot of sample with rotation over time on WEB!! google is your friend...

```
public IEnumerator RotateToDirection(Transform transform, Vector3 position, float timeToRotate)
{
    var startRotation = transform.rotation;
    var direction = position - transform.position;
    var finalRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
    var t = 0f;
    while (t <= 1f)
    {
        t += Time.deltaTime / timeToRotate;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(startRotation, finalRotation, t);
        yield return null;
    }
    transform.rotation = finalRotation;
}
```